# 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: python, mysql, flask, bcrypt

I am using MYSQL for storing username and their corresponding salted and hashed password it is giving me continuously this error.

```
1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '$2b$12$0NwXT7hoHPBK.ywn/r5f3OWQKrF9o1/wUJt7u1eFtn3Se2XCmiXdm'')' at line 1
```

My Table Name is *hassle_free_register* and it table structure is as follows as :

```
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| USER_ID  | int          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| USERNAME | varchar(255) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| PASSWORD | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Code For Storing the password :

```
@app.route('/register' ,methods =['POST'])
def register():
   try:
      NAME = request.form['USER_NAME']
      PASSWORD = request.form['USER_PASSWORD']
      if(len(NAME)==0):
         raise ValueError("USERNAME CANNOT BE EMPTY")
      if(len(PASSWORD)<=8):
         raise ValueError("PASSWORD LENGTH TOO SHORT")
      if(len(PASSWORD)>=30):
         raise ValueError("PASSWORD LENGTH TOO LONG") 
      HASHEDPASS = bcrypt.hashpw(PASSWORD.encode('utf-8'),bcrypt.gensalt())    
      mycursor.execute("insert into Hassle_Free_Register(USERNAME,PASSWORD) values('{USER_NAME}','{USER_PASSWORD}');".format(USER_NAME = NAME,USER_PASSWORD = str(HASHEDPASS)))
      mydb.commit()
      return jsonify("REGISTERED SUCCESSFULLY") 
   except ValueError as error:
      return jsonify({"message":str(error)}),403
   except mysql.connector.Error as error:
      print(error)
      # return error
      return jsonify({"message":str(error)}), 404
```

Please help ! I am using Flask Framework.

Comment: Don't use string formatting, use parameters to `cursor.execute()`.

Comment: Instead of crafting the query by hand, use parameters to send the arguments to the query. It will take care of escaping for you.

Comment: i am new to python and mysql can you please write code to make me understand what you are trying to convey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you see the problem?  Your hashed password contains single quote marks.  That screws up your quoting.  So, let the database connector do it:

```
mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO HassleFree_Register(USERNAME,PASSWORD) VALUES(?,?);", (NAME, HASHEDPASS))
```

Depending on the database, you might need `%s` instead of `?`.

As a stylistic note, it's not considered good form to use ALL CAPS for variable names.  That's fine for global constants, but variables should be `username` or `user_name`.

Comment: This is working correctly ! , also i understood my mistake . I cannot upvote this as i do not have that much reputation ,sorry :)

Comment: The question is tagged `mysql`, why do you say "depending on the database"?

Comment: @Tim Roberts . I will follow your stylistic note too ! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`HASHEDPASS` apparently contains a `'` character, which is ending the string `'{USER_PASSWORD}'` early.

Use parameters to `cursor.execute()` rather than substituting variables directly into the SQL string.

```
mycursor.execute("insert into Hassle_Free_Register(USERNAME,PASSWORD) values(%s, %s);", (NAME, HASHEDPASS))
```

Comment: Thanks @Barmar for answer , This is working correctly but i cannot upvote now as i am low on reputation , also i cannot upvote your answer as the above one is also correct. But still thanks for helping me out. Also i understood my mistake too !